# Host is subscribed to own Events

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I've got two different NSB Hosts (Host A, Host B)

Here's what I expect to happen when publishing events between the two hosts.

- Host A publishes IHappened
- Host B is subscribed to the queue and has a handler for IHappened. The IHandleMessages handler is invoked.

Done.

Here's whats for me.

- Host A publishses IHappened
- Host B is subscribed... Handler is invoked
- Host A tries to find a handler and throws error:

  ```
  System.InvalidOperationException: No handlers could be found for message type: SomeAssembly.Messages.Events.IHappened
     at NServiceBus.LoadHandlersBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\LoadHandlersBehavior.cs:line 31
     at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain1.Invoke() in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 39
     at NServiceBus.ApplyIncomingMessageMutatorsBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\MessageMutator\ApplyIncomingMessageMutatorsBehavior.cs:line 23
     at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain1.Invoke() in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 3
  ```

The config for Host A does not reference its own Queue, so I'm confused as to why its trying to process the event.

```
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings />
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

Why is Host A trying to process its own event?

Questions answered:

- Both end points are uniquely named
- Using RabbitMq for transport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a guess, but:

Are your endpoints (and thus queues) named the same?  Your endpoints need to have unique names.

Edit:

Ok, strike 1.  :)

Still, I think Host A is somehow subscribed to IHappened.  If you are using Raven, and know how to navigate its UI, look in the database named the same as Host A's endpoint, and look at the Subscription collections.  Find the IHappened MessageType and see if Host A is subscribed.  If it is, you may have to remove it manually (obviously, don't do this during business hours if this is production!).

If this is indeed the problem, you should run Host A again after fixing it and ensure that it doesn't get re-added for some reason.

Comment: Nope, both have unique names. I'll updated the question with that information.

Comment: I'm using Rabbit for transport and Raven for persistence. Currently  I've got no sagas implemented so everything is in Rabbit. How can you see who is subscribed to queues from Rabbit?

Comment: Subscription storage is part of persistence, so it will be in Raven if that's what you're using.

Comment: Rabbit has native pubsub support so the substorage in raven doesn't come into play. Check the bindings inside rabbit using the rabbit admin ui?

Comment: Interesting--I had no idea it worked differently for different transports.

Comment: I realized I never came back to this. Wiping Rabbit did the trick.